# Change date pattern from shortDate() format in JodaTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, locale, jodatime

I have a LocalDate and I would like to print the date with day and month as 2 digit and the year as 4 digit, based on Locale format pattern.
Actually, I can use the DateTimeFormatter to set the short date, but unfortunately "I can't" change the default pattern...Is there a method to do this?

Below, I explain this with an example:

```
Locale l = Locale.ITALIAN;
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2014, 8, 28);
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput1 = DateTimeFormat.shortDate().withLocale(l);
System.out.println( "Output1: " + formatterOutput1.print(localDate));

l = Locale.ENGLISH;
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput2 = DateTimeFormat.shortDate().withLocale(l);
System.out.println( "Output2: " + formatterOutput2.print(localDate));
```

This is the result:

```
Output1: 28/08/14
Output2: 8/28/14
```

So, the output is correct, but I expect this:

```
Output1: 28/08/2014
Output2: 08/28/2014
```

How can I change the default pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `shortDate()` a way to do it is by using `forStyle()` using the `S` for Date and `-` for Time

```
DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", Locale.ITALIAN);
```

Then do a String replace on the Pattern to change your `yy` into `yyyy`

Example:

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate(2014, 8, 28);
String pattern = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", Locale.ITALIAN);
pattern = pattern.replace("yy", "yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
System.out.println("Output1: " + formatterOutput1.print(localDate));
```

Which will print:

```
Output1: 28/08/2014
```

Same goes with ENGLISH Locale:

```
String patternEnglish = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", Locale.ENGLISH);
patternEnglish = patternEnglish.replace("yy", "yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(patternEnglish);
System.out.println("Output2: " + formatterOutput2.print(localDate));
```

Which will print:

```
Output2: 8/28/2014
```

**Note that with this approach** you don't have to worry about knowing all Locale formats if you only care about making the YEAR part 4 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You should compose your own format pattern. In your particular case it will be:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: yeah, could be a solution...but I need to separate every Locale. I think that the solution above is most correct! Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: While [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25551380/642706) is technically correct, I agree with this answer. Either let the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and [`forStyle`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle(java.lang.String)) do their job in localizing *or* define your own pattern. Mixing the two (altering the localized output) seems like a hack to me, and likely to cause problems.

Comment: Ok, the main problem is a internationalization process for my java project (android app). In england (for example), the date format is different to germany/france/italy etc... and the user must see the correct format based on her Locale.
I can use only forPattern() method, but is not based on Locale. With the previous solution, I can manage every date format and send to user the correct output...
I think... :)